# Very Slow Loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a piece of code which I'm having trouble with. Modified slightly here to work as a simple reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "ID" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  "max_ID" = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6),
  "start_date" = as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01")),
  "end_date_1" = as.Date(c("2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2019-12-31")),
  "end_date_2" = as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
)

num_rows <- nrow(df) #6

for(row_idx in 1:num_rows)
{
  if(df$ID[row_idx] == df$max_ID[row_idx])
  {
    df$end_date_2[row_idx] <- df$end_date_1[row_idx]
  }
  else
  {
    df$end_date_2[row_idx] <- df$start_date[row_idx + 1] %m-% days(1)
  }
}
```

In this trivial example it runs very quickly, but in the actual application it is VERY slow. It's working its way through a very long table (but even so, it is a lot slower than some other loops working through the same table).

Is there something in particular about the codethat is causing the problem (eg. the lubridate "%m-%" bit)?

What would be much better of course would be to "vectorise" this because I'm sure it would run much faster. What makes it difficult is the reference to the following row (the `[row_idx + 1]` bit). Is there a way to do this without using a (slow) loop?

Thank you.

Comment: This would reference the following row `c(tail(df$start_date, -1), NA)`. There are packages offering this as functions (e.g., `data.table::shift` and afaik there is also something in dplyr).

Comment: Thank you. I work with dplyr a lot so perhaps I should look at the documentation for that package & see what I can find...

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need a for loop for this, `dplyr` package is easier (to read and write)

```
df <- df %>% mutate(end_date_2 = ifelse(ID == max_ID, end_date_1 , lead(start_date) %m-% days(1)),
                    end_date_2 = as.Date(end_date_2, origin="1970-01-01" ))
```

I use the lead to replace your [row_idx + 1] part. Only issue (for me) is that end_date2 was put to numeric in the ifelse statement, while you want to keep it a date, so that is what I use the second mutation for (although you can probably do it all at once).

Comment: Ahhh ok there is "lead" and "lag" in dplyr...I shall investigate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop or external libraries other than the lubridate package you are already using. Just use the built-in `which.max` function

```
require(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  "ID" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  "max_ID" = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6),
  "start_date" = as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01")),
  "end_date_1" = as.Date(c("2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2019-12-31")),
  "end_date_2" = as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
)

simple_method <- function(df)
{
  df$end_date_2[-num_rows] <- df$start_date[-1] - days(1)
  df$end_date_2[which.max(df$ID)] <- df$end_date_1[which.max(df$ID)]
  return(df)
}

original_method <- function(df)
{
  num_rows <- nrow(df)
  for(row_idx in 1:num_rows)
  {
    if(df$ID[row_idx] == df$max_ID[row_idx])
    {
      df$end_date_2[row_idx] <- df$end_date_1[row_idx]
    }
    else
    {
      df$end_date_2[row_idx] <- df$start_date[row_idx + 1] %m-% days(1)
    }
  }
  return(df)
}
```

Which gives the following benchmark results:

```
> microbenchmark(original_method(df), simple_method(df))
Unit: milliseconds
                expr       min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
 original_method(df) 13.977496 14.18948 14.879323 14.26715 14.577343 26.44665   100
   simple_method(df)  2.562268  2.59546  2.966167  2.61582  2.722923 10.52761   100
```